# In which direction Hibernate orm-mapping works

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a rather simple (probably) question, but somehow struggling to find an answer.
How does hibernate map nested entities to java objects? Does it starts its mapping from high-level entities and stops on encountering null-values in ResultSet, or it starts from the lowest-level entities and check all of the hierarchy?
The first path seems to be more natural, but yet I didn't find a concrete answer or any way to configure this

**EDIT**

By nested entities I suppose something like this:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    public Long id;
    public String foo;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    public Long Id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
    public A bar;
}
```

Where *bar* field is nested entity for B

**One more edit**

By ORM-mapping I meant mapping on select query call - so, if table *B* has no records and we execute any select-query to find entities of *B*, does Hibernate atempt to find and map entities of *A* ? Futhermore, if we have

```
@Entity
public class C {
    public Long Id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bId")
    public B foobar;
}
```

and yet there are no records in table *B*, some in *C* and some in *A*, when we use any find methods for *C*, does Hibernate attempt to find and map entities of *A*?

Comment: What do you mean with `nested entities`? Could you show an example?

Comment: Do you mean entities there a represented by a subclass?

Comment: @Davide I've edited my question, hopefully it adds more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate ORM won't create a proxy for *-to-one association that can be null (`@OneToOne(optional=false)`). If the element is missing in the db it will be null when the entity is created. So, using your example, `C.foobar` will be null if there is no row on the table B in the db. The same applies to the other *-to-one associations.

If the element is not optional, it might load it lazily and therefore assign a proxy to it.

To expand a bit about your question.
This is a one-to-one association. More in general, what you call `nested` is an association in Hibernate ORM. You can find all the details about these types of mapping in [the Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations).

For your specific example:

```
    @Entity
    public class A {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "aId")
        public Long id;
        public String foo;
    }

    @Entity
    public class B {
        @Id
        public Long id;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
        public A bar;
    }
```

Hibernate ORM will create the following tables in Postgres:

```
create table A (aId int8 not null, foo varchar(255), primary key (aId))
create table B (Id int8 not null, aId int8, primary key (Id))
alter table if exists B add constraint FK3mifipyyn4ao31rn7kftqknuc foreign key (aId) references A
```

Basically:

- Table A with columns `aid` and `foo`
- Table B with columns `id` and `aid`
- Table B column `aid` has a foreign constraint to Table A column `aid`

You can find all the details about [one-to-one mapping in the Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one).

If you run the HQL query `from B`, Hibernate ORM will run the following SQL:

```
1. select * from B;

2. select * from A a.where a.aid = ?
```

if the HQL is `from C`

```
1. select * from C;

2. select * from B b left outer join A a on b.aId = a.aId where b.id=?;
```

In both cases, the second query only runs if there are results for the first one.

Keep in mind that this is a basic example and the type of queries executed
will change based on the configuration and the mapping of the entities.
You can actually tweak this behaviour with small changes to the mapping (Lazy/Eager fetching, optional, using bidirectional associations, ...) or the queries. I'm not going through all the possible mappings and you should write your own tests and check what SQL is logged.
Hibernate ORM might also skip some queries if some of the entities or the query has been cached.

Comment: Shame on me once again, I've added more info on question

Comment: I've added the  generated SQL queries to the answer

Comment: So, in this certain case, if second HQL from C doesn't return any records of B, no mapping to java objects neither of B nor of A (which is what bugs me the most) would be performed internally, right?

Comment: Basically, you wanted to know if it returns null or a proxy when doing one-to-one?

Comment: Hibernate ORM will set the value to null if the element is missing for *-to-one association. Because the element can be null it cannot load it lazily and therefore there is no point in having a proxy.

Comment: Actually, I was interested in all proxy / null mapping shenanigans, but wasn't able to explain it properly due to my poor terminology. Yet it's clear I should investigate it furhter for my own sake. Thank you for the explanation, Davide!